# Kafka: How to get last modified time for a topic i.e. last message added to any partition of the topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Our use case is to delete stale/unused topics from kafka i.e. if a topic (on all partitions) doesn't have any new message in last 7 days then we would consider it as stale/unused and delete it.

Many google results suggested to add timestamp to messages and then parse it. For new topics & messages that soultion would work but our existing topics & messages doesn't have any timestamp in them.

How can I get this working ?.

Answer (score 1):

`kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime()` will return the latest message added to a queue. You can use the `Simple Consumer API` to determine which offset to read from.

For more details take look at the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) page

Comment: With latestTime() we can get the last offset of the message but it wouldn't give me the timestamp of it i.e. when that message was inserted into the queue. To determine stale topic or not I need to know if message is older than 7 days.

Comment: If you don't require msgs longer than 7 days then why still keep them in the queue ? Additionally you can put timestamp while producing and  track them at the consumer end using the simple consumer