# Get last modified date of a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I know that is possible to get the latest offset of a kafka but is it possible to get the timestamp of the last change of a kafka topic via the kafka console scripts ?

I saw this question [Kafka: How to get last modified time for a topic i.e. last message added to any partition of the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735852/kafka-how-to-get-last-modified-time-for-a-topic-i-e-last-message-added-to-any) but with no real answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the timestamp straight forward from the script. Instead you can see the timestamp using the console-consumer script. It shows the `CreateTime` for a message
As mentioned by @Sreekiran also, use the property "print.timestamp" as below :

```
ncsv@ubuntu:/data/softwares/kafka_2.11-2.0.0$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testJsonTopic1 --property print.timestamp=true --from-beginning
CreateTime:1544445041225        {"id": "9","name": "wis"}
CreateTime:1544518616282        {"id": "19","name": "wes"}
CreateTime:1544520723808        {"id": "1","name": "test1"}
CreateTime:1544446690508        {"id": "9","name": "wes"}
CreateTime:1544445375123        {"id": "9","name": "wes"}
CreateTime:1544520388080        {"id": "20","name": "test1"}
```

It will show the time when the event was written in the cluster.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the current command `--property print.timestamp=true` That will print the timestamp `CreateTime:1544706749268`.